# sIFR ok on one browser not on on onother (not trivial!)

Tags: debugging, rendering, sifr, render

I use newest sIFR version. It works on some browsers and does not on other. Flash version doesn't seem to matter, and on one computer it works on IE8 but won't go with FF3.

The thing is that if it fails to work it just displays nothing, no regular text/typefaces, just an empty space.

The site is http://www.winaisery.pl/

Do you have any clues?

Comment: All I can tell you is "Works fine here." (Vista, Firefox 3.5.1, Flash 10.0)

Comment: Good to know, thanks :) yet this inconsistency (it works but not in every configuration) is deadly...

Comment: A suggestion to check out Cufon: http://wiki.github.com/sorccu/cufon/about 
A lot easier to implement.

Comment: Looks like you've switched to Cufón now?

Answer (score 0):

you might want to test if your flash player is [correctly installed](http://www.adobe.com/shockwave/welcome/)